# Malayalam font embed in adobe flash professional cs5

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I want to create malayalam supported font using adobe flash professional cs5, in embed option i can choose malayalam font family dropdown but character range is not available for malayalam

Comment: Did you try a **different** Malayam font? Issue could be specific to that used font file (depends on creator's settings). Does Arial Unicode (as a test) allow you to choose ranges? I ask because since there are UTF-8 codes for upppercase & lowercase Malayam characters, you should be able to select something for your ranges.

Comment: yes, your right. I am creating font swf in two languages Armenian and Malayalam.i have installed those two language ttf in my system and created TLF textfield in flash professional cs5. In properties panel i have selected Armenian and Malayalam font families,then embed button click there is font embedding window in that options tab character range is listed, from that list i can choose Armenian glyphs but Malayalam glyphs not available

Comment: Thank you. I am creating font swf in two languages Armenian and Malayalam.i have installed those two language ttf in my system and i have two .fla files each have TLF textfield. when click on embed button, Font embedding window is opening, In that options tab, character range is listed, for armenian.fla i can choose Armenian(0/101 glyphs) from the check box,but for Malayalam.fla its not available,all other default check boxes(Basic Latin,Chinese,Japanese,Arabic,Hebrew etc) are available. the same happen for Tamil,Bengali,etc."Also include these characters" is only option to include malayam.

Comment: It's likely the armenian font has a piece of metadata to designate local language glyphs, and your malayalam font doesn't. Ask for a better font or glyph range.

Comment: Actual problem not with font and its glyph range, it is with flash cs5 , when i click on new font, in font embedding window, options tab character range is limited,Malayalam,Tamil,Telugu,Gurmukhi,Gujarati and Oriya is not available